# How to style HTML Pagination

Tags: html, css

I have created a `Pagination` which will show/hide div based on the active Page as here https://jsfiddle.net/bogaso/qh7cpxzv/11/

However, I failed to apply style on the Navigation bar. Particularly I want to apply below two styles at the minimum level:

1. I want the Navigation bar will stay at the `center` of the page, with specific `margin` at top
2. Furthermore I want to apply `border` around each page number as in https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_ex_pagination_border_round

However when I try to wrap the `<a> tag` with some `<div>`, I lost all control in the navigation, i.e. below code fails to apply any style

```
<div class = 'Top'>
<a href="#" rel="page-1" class="active A1">1</a>
<a href="#" rel="page-2" class = "A1">2</a>
<a href="#" rel="page-3" class = "A1">3</a>
<a href="#" rel="page-4" class = "A1">4</a>
<a href="#" rel="page-5" class = "A1">7</a>
<a href="#" rel="page-6" class = "A1">6</a>
</div>
```

Any help on how to **apply Style** in the navigation bar would be highly appreciated.

Also is it possible to implement the same **based solely on `HTML + CSS`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your CSS code is at the beginning.
You are adding a rule to hide all `div` elements, and this is causing the problem when you wrap the `<a>` tags with a `div`.
The solution is to apply the CSS hiding only for the page elements.

So, remove the CSS rule at the top and style the `AAA` class instead:

```
.AAA {
  display: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.AAA.active { display: block; }
```

To center the pagination controls, I recommend using the Flexible Box Layout Module, aka flex.

This would be the CSS rule to center the pagination and keep its margin:

```
.Top {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

As for your question, it isn't possible to do this using only CSS and HTML, at least not in a good way. CSS shouldn't dictate the behaviour of a webpage.

For your development, I really suggest learning proper HTML style guide, and especially trying to be consistent. I noticed sometimes you use single quotes other times double quotes fort HTML attributes. It should always be double quotes without any spaces betweens the equal sign and the quotes :)

**In the end, the code will be:**

```js
$('a.A1').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
    
    return false;
});
```

```css
.A1 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.AAA {
  display: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.AAA.active { display: block; }


.Top {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Top a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.Top a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

.Top a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

.Top a:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.Top a:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-1" class="active AAA">p1</div>
<div id="page-2" class="AAA">p2</div>
<div id="page-3" class="AAA">p3</div>
<div id="page-4" class="AAA">p4</div>
<div id="page-5" class="AAA">p5</div>
<div id="page-6" class="AAA">p6</div>


<div class="Top">
  <a href="#" rel="page-1" class="active A1">1</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-2" class="A1">2</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-3" class="A1">3</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-4" class="A1">4</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-5" class="A1">7</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-6" class="A1">6</a> 
</div>
```

Here's a working js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ovitrif/o8h3nrjb/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below HTML, CSS and JS.

```js
$('.Top a').click(function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

```css
div.AAA {
  display: none
}

div.active {
  display: block;
}

.Top {
  display: inline-block;
}

.Top a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.Top a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

.Top a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.Top a:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.Top a:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.AAA {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-1" class="active AAA">p1</div>
<div id="page-2" class='AAA'>p2</div>
<div id="page-3" class='AAA'>p3</div>
<div id="page-4" class='AAA'>p4</div>
<div id="page-5" class='AAA'>p5</div>
<div id="page-6" class='AAA'>p6</div>

<div class='Top'>
  <a href="#" rel="page-1" class="active A1">1</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-2" class="A1">2</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-3" class="A1">3</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-4" class="A1">4</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-5" class="A1">7</a>
  <a href="#" rel="page-6" class="A1">6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: careful with  `div {display: none}` tho ;)